# How do you stop a columned image from going outside the div container?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a webpage that I'm developing, and have an image inside a column that keeps on overlapping the body! Is there a way to figure this stuff out?

Also, I'm fairly new to coding, so I'm kindof surprised that I got this far without complications till now!

```css
  html {
    --l0: calc(100% - 1px), #cea18b;
    --l1: 0% 25%, #0000 0% 50%;
    --g: repeating-conic-gradient(#cea18b var(--l1));
    background: 
      var(--g), 
      radial-gradient(
      closest-side, 
      transparent var(--l0)
      ), 
        linear-gradient(
            90deg,
            #0000 0 25%, 
            currentcolor 0 75%, 
            #d68571 0
        ), 
        repeating-conic-gradient(
            #829891 var(--l1)), 
            var(--g), 
            radial-gradient(
                closest-side, 
                currentcolor var(--l0)
    );
    background-size:
        9.375em 9.375em, 
        4.6875em 4.6875em, 
        9.375em, 
        18.75em 18.75em, 
        0.75em 0.75em, 
        0.375em 0.375em;
    color: #31334a;
  }
main{
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  #introduction{
    text-indent: 2em;
      #cat1{
        float: auto;
        /*Trying to center image*/
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
        overflow: clip; 
        position: sticky;
        display: flex;
        img{
          border-radius: 25px;                        
          border-style: solid;
          border-color:#31334a;
          border-width: 5px;
        }
      }
body{
    background-color: #fdf5e2;
    margin: 0 10vw;
    padding: 0;
    #i2{
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 150px;
        column-count: 2;
        column-width: 10rem;
        align-content: space-evenly;
        min-width: 700px;
        position: relative;
        white-space: normal;
        overflow: hidden;
        img{
          height: 500px;
          float: right;
          right: 20px;
        }
    }
    #i3{
      text-align: center;
      text-indent: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
        <div id="i2">
            <p> Paragraph 1 </p>
            <p> Paragraph 2 </p>
            <img 
              alt="Map of Isle of Man" 
             src="https://www.gov.im/media/1371840/constituency-overview-map.png">
            <p id="i3">Centered paragraph</p>
        </div>
```

I tried fixing the text from overlapping the image, but now the image overlaps the body... I tried using the `overlap: hidden;` code, but it didn't work, and I tried searching the internet for answers before posting this.

Comment: You've left a `<p>` on the line where `<p id="i3">`
It should be  `<p id="i3"></p>`

Comment: edited your code and added the missing closing p tag </p